# How to check if all nodes are enabled using pipe?

Tags: angular

I have tried to write a pipe, that takes an node and checks if all children nodes are enabled (excluding parent):

```
@Pipe({ name: 'allchildEnabled', pure: false })
export class AllChildEnabledChildPipe implements PipeTransform {
    private enabled = true;

    transform<T extends ITreeNode>(node: T): boolean {
        this.search(node);

        return this.enabled;
    }

    search<T extends ITreeNode>(node: T) {
        if (!node || !this.enabled) return;
        if (node?.children) {
            node.children.forEach((child: T) => {
                this.enabled = child?.enabled;
                this.search(child);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But this allways says me that all children enabled (boolean true).

Where did I make mistake?

My second attempt:

```
function search(node: any): boolean {
    if (!node || !node?.enabled) return false;
    if (node?.children) {
           for (let child of node.children) return search(child);

    }

    return true;
}

let tree = {id: 1, enabled: true, children: [{id: 2, enabled: true}, {id: 3, enabled: true}, {id: 3, enabled: true, children: [{id: 4, enabled: true}]}]};

console.log(search(tree));
```

Comment: try to make that pipe as impure

Comment: this doesn't look like the job of a `Pipe`. Actually.. this doesn't look like angular at all. I don't know what you are technically trying to achieve, but a directive is probably more in place than this behemoth ;)

Comment: Could you share an sample with directive?

Comment: I have made this, seems works for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4MwVwOwYwFwJYHsrAM4FMCGAnGALACiiQBMMAuYLKATwBphyMAHYAXmAAZG04s4lYACMkSADbZUnODggYAlFVESpwAN4BYAFCg9wBGGCEAhCXILgODHAg5UYLOMwBuHftCHT5jAH4AdBhQWMKSpMAAZBFMGKyW1rb24E6u7h4GRsRkfv4ECOKk1lCWWrrpemBIOMaScMB5BcBIRj65+PmFQZZ8Ahgc6Nh4RA2kjMxsANTAAIy8-IIKbmUeAL46aR4Jdqg9gkt6a9obwLXAsrH96gikVLP17QVFVADaVzfAAEyMQSFhVLLyFaMN5UADM32CoQw7wBGCBGmuYIhv2h-zkGEYIyewFeiOAABZkVCYejMQ9OlAXiCCUS-slnHCALorZnMpbHGAoNCqfziJAAc0ImFwBEI50UiyAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forEach function is working incorrectly.

In your example, if the latest child will be enabled you will have `enabled as true` in your pipe, but How I could understand from your question description you need to make `enabled as false` when you have at least one child as disabled(not enabled)

Try to use this answer

```
@Pipe({ name: 'allchildEnabled', pure: false })
export class AllChildEnabledChildPipe implements PipeTransform {
    private enabled = true;

    transform<T extends ITreeNode>(node: T): boolean {
        this.search(node);

        return this.enabled;
    }

    search<T extends ITreeNode>(node: T) {
        if (!node || !this.enabled) return;

        if (node?.children) {
           this.enabled = !node.children.find((child: T) => {
                this.search(child);
                return !child?.enabled;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But I didn't tested this yet, let me know if this example will not work for you.

Comment: Thank you. but I need skip first node, parent node, how to do that?

Comment: Hi @user13314476 what you mean for the parent Node shouldn't work? It is not working for the parent it is looping over the children

Comment: I mean this. seem it works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4MwVwOwYwFwJYHsrAM4FMCGAnGALACiiQBMMAuYLKATwBphyMAHYAXmAAZG04s4lYACMkSADbZUnODggYAlFVESpwAN4BYAFCg9wBGGCEAhCXILgODHAg5UYLOMwBuHftCHT5jAH4AdBhQWMKSpMAAZBFMGKyW1rb24E6u7h4GRsRkfv4ECOKk1lCWWrrpemBIOMaScMB5BcBIRj65+PmFQZZ8Ahgc6Nh4RA2kjMxsANTAAIy8-IIKbmUeAL46aR4Jdqg9gkt6a9obwLXAsrH96gikVLP17QVFVADaVzfAAEyMQSFhVLLyFaMN5UADM32CoQw7wBGCBGmuYIhv2h-zkGEYIyewFeiOAABZkVCYejMQ9OlAXiCCUS-slnHCALorZnMpbHGAoNCqfziJAAc0ImFwBEI50UiyAA

Comment: I just checked my provided example is working how you described. Maybe I got you wrong?

Comment: But I am actually agreed with @Poul Kruijt. Try to use a directive, or find a better workaround

Comment: Could you show how to use directive in my case?

Comment: can you share Pipe Usage example, I mean HTML block